# How to find the hash of a Docker image?

Tags: docker, cut

When i use this docker command:

```
docker inspect 'name of my container' | grep sha256
```

i get this back:

```
"Image": "sha256:345hu5j3h53jk234",
```

How can I use th **--cut -d command** to only get the **sha256:345hu5j3h53jk234** without quotation marks?

Currently i am trying something like that:

```
docker inspect 'name of my container' | grep sha256 | cut -d ","-f2
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you *need* to use `cut`? Or can you use other, more appropriate commands? `docker inspect` returns JSON, you should use `jq` to parse it.

Comment: Do you mean like that:  "docker inscpect 'name of my container' | grep sha256 | jq" ? I get an error telling me that i have to install jq. I am not allowed to install, so i guess i have to use cut

Comment: You can *always* perform local installation, this requires no special permissions (in the case of `jq` it’s enough to download and unpack the binary). But OK, if you’re unwilling to install `jq` you can make do without it, though the solution is by necessity brittle. Your current solution has a few typos but at any rate I’d suggest using `grep` without `cut`: `docker inspect ‹name of container› | grep -o 'sha256:[^"]*'`

Comment: Thank you man, it works for me!

Answer (score 5):

[`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/), like many of the other list-type Docker commands, takes a `--format` option that lets you use the Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language to reformat the results.  This works best if you're just trying to pick out simple fields:

```sh
docker inspect container-name -f '{{ .Image }}'
```

The standard shell tools are a little more oriented towards line-oriented text files than structured files like JSON.  A comment suggested using `jq` and that would be a good tool here.  If that's really not an option, you *can* do this with **sed**(1):

```sh
docker inspect container-name | sed -ne 's/.*"Image": "\([^"]*\)",$/\1/p'
```

To break down that `sed` command a little more:

- `sed -n` causes lines to not be printed by default.
- `s/RE/\1/p` tries to match the current line against the regular expression; if it does, replace the line with the first `\(...\)` group, and print it.
- `.*"Image":` matches arbitrary text up through the JSON `"Image":` tag.
- `\(...\)` captures a group for the `\1` replacement.
- `[^"]*` matches any number of characters that aren't double quotes.
- `",$` matches a double-quote, a comma, and the end of the line.

Unless you're nodding along with this explanation, I'd prefer the `docker inspect -f` or `jq` approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is "the" hash you are probably looking for:

```
docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $CONT_IMAGE
```

---

```
# caution: on the other hand, this hash below is NOT comparable 
# with image hashes displayed elsewhere:
# - in the Docker Hub (or other registry) - as "DIGEST" or
# - in the field imageID shown in the k8s Pod's JSON or YAML 
# (e.g. as returned by `kubectl get pod --selector app=ml-scraper-py39-jup -o jsonpath="{..imageID}"`):

$ docker inspect $CONT_IMAGE -f '{{ .ContainerConfig.Image }}'
```